# regression estimator as covariance

Tags: regression, covariance, estimators

im currently looking at a formula for regression estimators, and they say: $Cov(y_i,s_i)/V(s_i)=E(h(s_i)(s_i-E(s_i)))/E(s_i(s_i-E(s_i)))$. This equality is mysterious to me.$ h(s_i)$ is defined as$ E(y_i | s_i = t)$. but how is this a classical variance formula? what about $(y_i-E(y_i))$. I have tried reformulating it to fit but to no avail. Also: isnt there an E(s_i) missing in the denominator?

Comment: Can you link a url or a text name for what you are reading?

Comment: yes, its mostly harmless econometrics, p.81 and 57etc,  see ftp://nozdr.ru/biblio/kolxo3/G/GL/Angrist%20J.D.,%20Pischke%20J.-S.%20Mostly%20Harmless%20Econometrics%20(PUP,%202008)(ISBN%20069112034X)(O)(290s)_GL_.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It helps to note that $cov(a, b) = E(ab) - E(a)E(b) $. Further note expectation is a linear operator meaning, $E(a +b) =E(a) + E(b) $.

The Y in regression is defined as a conditional mean plus an error. The error term is orthogonal to the predictors so their covariance is 0.

Comment: thanks for your help, if I try to derive it this way I end up with: E(E(y_i I s_i) (s_i) - E(y_i)E(s_i). I seem to be missing the rest. And im still not sure how they get the variance of s_i in the denominator. Unfortunately, they don't really derive their formulas in the book :(. Thanks again for your help!